# Presenting views of VCs from Page Curl in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, page-curl

This may be covered elsewhere, but I am either not finding an answer that fits/works, or am just not understanding what is happening.

I have a VC with a map view on it.  There is a page curl that reveals buttons just like in the iOS Maps app to change the main view (from map to list to grid).

When I select one of the buttons under the page curl, everything works fine if I am going to/from the map view (which is essentially just dismissing the view controller that is currently displayed).  But if I try to go from list to grid or grid to list, I get:

```
    Attempt to present <a ViewController: 0x9d2f280> on <parent ViewController: 0xc080bd0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I have a handler on, let's say, the list view's VC to handle the grid button click, which uncurls the page and then calls back to the parent (presenting VC) to do the work, which is just:

```
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];
```

The logic seems correct to me, but I keep getting the parent VC view not in view hierarchy.

What am I doing wrong?